# Implementation of queues using kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue

I want to implement a queue mechanism using kafka. But could not find anywhere that if it's possible to just peek data from the queue created for any topic without moving forward into it.

I want to read data from the queue and on the basis of different conditions want to remove the existing message or add another message into this queue. Also, is it possible to use a single kafka server from different machines.

I referred to tutorialspoint for learning more about it.

Thanks in advance. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot peek into kafka also you cannot delete messages. You can only play with consumer offset.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Kakfa scales with multiple partitions per topic, and it doesn't give any ordering guarantee between partitions. So don't use kafka if you want strict ordering. Within a consumer group, if you want n consumers per topic, you need to have atleast n partitions.

Consumers don't remove messages, they commit the offset of a message. Default configuration in most clients is to auto commit offset on read. You can re-insert messages into the topic anytime. But you cannot skip a message and expect to process it later.

You can connect as many machines as you want to a kafka server. Typically, you have multiple servers as a kafka cluster, with replication for fault tolerance.

Comment: *cannot skip a message and expect to process it later* -- There are tools to rewind the consumer offset

Comment: Agree, one can reconsume 'all' messages by resetting the offset. But cannot reset and expect to consume only skipped messages. (well, one can write a function that determines a message as processed or not, but there are probably better ways to do this)